# Take pointer with its datatype as a parameter

Tags: c++, pointers

I need process an array whose data-type is either float64_t or uint32_t. I want to make a function such that the pointer to the given array can be taken as a parameter to the function in this way:

```
void func_name(array_type* ptr_name, int count, data_type x)
//x can be float64_t or uint32_t
```

As you can see, beforehand I don't know the data-type of the pointer. How do I approach this problem in C++?

Comment: Please elaborate. I don't know templates. Can you put up a short example?

Comment: Can't you create two versions of `fund_name`?  One with `float64_t*`, and the other with `uint32_t*`?

Comment: Look at jrok's answer.

Comment: If you don't know how to use templates (or what they are), I would *strongly* suggest you get a solid book on C++. It's a very critical part of the language, and its standard library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can overload the functions:

```
void func(float64_t* ptr, int count);
void func(uint32_t* ptr, int count);
```

or make a function template:

```
template<typename T>
void func(T* ptr, int count);
```

The "data-type" (sic) of an array (and pointers) is a part of its type, you don't need to do anything special. Whichever approach you decide to take, the compiler will figure out for you which function to call (or what T will be when instantiating a template).

```
template<typename T>
void func(T* ptr, int count) { }

int main()
{
    float f_arr[42] = {};
    int i_arr[84] = {};

    func(f_arr, 42);  // instantiates func with T = float
    func(i_arr, 84);  // instantiates func with T = int
}
```

Comment: Dumb question: Will this exact syntax i.e. template<typename T>
void func(T* ptr, int count); will work? i.e. Will the compiler be able to detect the datatype automatically?

Comment: @AdityaKumarPraharaj: You can even detect array **size** automatically: `template<typename T, size_t N> void func(T (&array) [N])` - assuming you have an array, of course, and not a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a template - as already suggested by *jrok*

```
template<typename T>
void func(T* ptr, int count);
```

This way you will be able to pass a pointer to ANY data type to your function. Essentially a template a template expands into a function for each  data type you use it with, at compile time.

if you however you want to over-complicate things, for obfuscation's sake let's say, you could do the following:

```
  void func(void* ptr, int count);
```

have you function take a generic pointer- you will have to do a reinterpret cast when calling the function to convert your pointer to a void*, and inside the function to convert it to which ever pointer type you like; and your count will be the number of bytes you want to read.

But I'm sure you will appreciate the simplicity and transparency of the first solution ( the template).